# Unity - Enemy AI walking through walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, artificial-intelligence

I've followed a Unity video available on YouTube to create a state machine for your AI, but however, when the enemy is patrolling, they walk through walls. I've tried to add the RigidBody component onto the enemy, but this completely bugs out their movement going to each waypoint.

Here is the code that makes the AI move to each waypoint

```
private void Look()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(enemy.eyes.transform.position, enemy.eyes.transform.forward, out hit, enemy.sightRange) && hit.collider.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        enemy.chaseTarget = hit.transform;
        InChaseState();
    }

}

void Patrol()
{
    enemy.meshRendererFlag.material.color = Color.green; //Test to see what state the enemy is in
    enemy.navMeshAgent.destination = enemy.waypoints[nextWaypoint].position; //Select the current waypoint
    enemy.navMeshAgent.Resume(); //Start walking again

    if (enemy.navMeshAgent.remainingDistance <= enemy.navMeshAgent.stoppingDistance && !enemy.navMeshAgent.pathPending) //Checking to see if we've reached our destination
    {
        nextWaypoint = (nextWaypoint + 1) % enemy.waypoints.Length; //Go to next waypoint and should loop as expected
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to edit this code to make the enemy walk around  walls in the map to reach each waypoint? Thanks.

Comment: The walls might not be carved out of the NavMesh?! The walls need a collider for the algorithm to do so. They also need to be navigational static (can be set in the static checkboxes dropdown) or a NavMesh obstacle, which is a component when I remember correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your walls are not baked into your navigation mesh.  In order to do this, if you have not already, add the Navigation window to your editor by clicking on Window->Navigation.  Select your wall in the scene, and in the Navigation pane on the Object tab, check the box that says Navigation Static.  Then press the bake button at the bottom right of the navigation pane. Provided your wall has a collider, you should see something like this:

[image]

The blue area denotes the places your navigation agent is allowed to walk.  You will notice the area around your wall is not blue, so your agents will not be able to walk through there.